# I can't run my own applets in browser

Tags: java, security, browser, applet

I can't run my Java applet in any browser - Java blocks it for security reason. I have Java 8, so I can't set security settings to medium. What I have to do? (in my own applets I mean applets that I wrote and it can't harm anything)

Comment: Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have to sign the applet before running it on the browser did you try signing your applet Jar. here is the signing commands.

You should be in the same directory in command prompt.

```
1.keytool -genkey -keyalg rsa -alias m4key  //m4key unique key
2.keytool -export -alias m4key -file bmcert.crt   //bmcert.crt certificate name
3.jar tvf Jarname.jar verify jar
4.jarsigner Jarname.jar m4key
5.jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs JarnameJarname.jar
```

But As you have mentioned you are using **Java 8** , A self signed jar is not allowed to run in the browser due to security reasons.

So

Please open **configure java** in settings and in security TAB put the **URL** of the html page which is using applet in Exception Site List

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The exception site list provides users with the option of allowing the same applets that would have been allowed by selecting the Medium option but on a site-by-site basis therefore minimizing the risk of using more permissive settings.

So as your localhost or whichever domain to exception list.
 [Read more here](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/jcp_security.xml)